# Why is deallocation slow?

Tags: c++, memory-management, set

I have a question for which I am unable to find answer on the net...

I have a set declared like this:

```
set<unsigned int> MySet
```

I am inserting a million random numbers generated with mersenne twister. Random generation and insertion are really fast (around a second for a million numbers), but deallocation is extremely slow (1 and a half minute).

Why is deallocation so slow? I am not using any custom destructors for the set.

Comment: I don't know what Op Sys you are using but it could be the memory is being re-compacted after each chunk is freed.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on? -O3

Comment: Windows 7x64. Compiling under Visual Studio 2010.
Is there any way to speed deallocation up?

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem in g++ or VS2010 http://codepad.org/KQj7Yfq4

Comment: @LokiAstari - Properties->C/C++ ->Optimization???
If so, all are off.

Comment: Build in release mode (that should turn most of them on) then re-time.

Comment: @twsaef
I am not adding them from 1 to 1M, I'm using Mersenne Twister to generate random numbers and insert them into the set
My numbers are all above 2^16

Comment: Wouldn't that not matter seeing as it's the deallocation you're experiencing speed issues with?

Comment: @LokiAstari - It worked!!! :D Can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: @SeeBeen: What was the new time?

Comment: 5 seconds.

Sorry for the late response. Just seen your comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile your code in release mode.

This does two things.

1. It turns on the optimizations which definitely help.
2. Also the memory management libraries are different for debug and release.
   The debug version of the library are built to allow for debugging and they maintain extra information (like marking de-allocated memory). All this extra processing does actually cost

   - The objective of the two version of the library are completely different. The release version is definitely optimized for speed the debug version is optimized for recovery and debugging.

Note this information is about DevStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it makes more sense to optimize allocation at the expense of deallocation, because many applications allocate without deallocating, but never vice versa. I've seen a similar pattern myself, in an application that mixed calls to `malloc` and `free` (as opposed to allocating and deallocating all at once).

I've never written a heap allocator, so I don't know if there's a deeper technical reason than that. When deallocating, adjacent free blocks must be found and coalesced. So the work is just fundamentally different.

90 seconds for 1 million small `free()`'s sounds quite slow. I've never really programmed Windows so I can't say if that's abnormal, but the system should be able to do much better.

The solution to your problem may be simply to skip freeing the objects before the program exits. You might try deriving a custom allocator from `std::allocator< unsigned int >` which makes `deallocate` a no-op.